# Purge cache in shopify web app

Tags: shopify

I am new to shopify and i have made some changes in one of my liquid file. Those changes are only visible in my live site when i hard refresh it. I need to purge cache of my app from my admin panel but couldn't find a option.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm also facing same and want to know if there is any option to remove cache from shopify admin ... but quite surprised to see there is no answer of the simple question yet after ~1.5 years :o